# How to make responsive <ul>?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-lists

I am trying to make a menu that has images instead of text. The 9 menu items break a line when the browser window shrinks. I want them to stay in a horizontal row and stay inside of my wrapper shrinking down in size.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.ksl.dev/wp-content/themes/ksl/img/ksl_news.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"/></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>

.nav {
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
/* I have a logo I'll be floating next to the nav */
.nav ul {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.nav ul li img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto; }
```

Try this
Also, take a look at the previous questions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666106/a-div-with-auto-resize-when-changing-window-width-height) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217355/automatically-resize-images-with-browser-size-using-css)

Comment: Thanks for your response but that didn't make a difference. Also those two links don't help clear up any confusion relevant to my specific situation as they tackle using background images and the body.